# Laravel 5.2 Popup User Notifications in Browser - Examples, Tips?

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

I have a guitar lessons site where I want to notify users (guests or logged in) about new notifications in real or near real time. I followed this example:

https://blog.pusher.com/writing-realtime-apps-with-laravel-5-and-pusher

I have an event set up, I have pusher account, I have things working as described in the above link.

But... I would like to have the notifications show up the way notifications appear on a lot of other sites. Namely, where a small popup appears on bottom right corner of browser regardless of where user is scrolled on current page. Or maybe where a message bar would appear on top of browser regaardless of where user is scrolled. In any case, I can't find examples of 5.2 notifications in this manner. All I see are examples of using a message div in a blade file and having the div populated via the pusher code in the blade. So I imagine to do do what I want is similar in spirit, just requiring some extra front end steps that are not clear to me yet.

Tips, examples appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [this](https://blog.pusher.com/create-web-notifications-using-laravel-pusher/) might help

Comment: Interesting, but looking at the classes I see it is a laravel 5.4 example. Maybe it is time to upgrade...

Comment: Actually, I was able to get that example working by removing use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatchable;
and use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets; Demo works nicely, but on my site, I added a list element as in the example, and notifications are passed ok, I see notification icon appear with a 1, but something about my site's view is preventing the notification dropdown window from displaying... Maybe I will submit new post to troubleshoot that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a common laravel blade file (with pusher code) and inherit that file in all blade templates.
Now using jquery growl (http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/) or alert box of your choice you can show the popups on any page you want.

Comment: The thing is I was hoping to implement in similar spirit to what is shown in the url csanonymus provided. Not exactly sure how to modify using growl, in a way that would keep the notifications formatting intact. In the example in the link above I really like how the notifications are implemented and displayed. I got it working sort of - if you see my comment above you'll see I am not 100% there. Will start new thread after I try more on my own! Thanks