# Laravel 5.2 Realtime Notifications via Pusher - track read/unread for guests and logged in visitors?

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

This sort of relates to my previous post, where I talk about **sending notifications to clients when I add a lesson on my guitar lessons site**:

[Laravel 5.2 Popup User Notifications in Browser - Examples, Tips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432395/laravel-5-2-popup-user-notifications-in-browser-examples-tips)

I have been able to get basic notifications working by following this example:

https://blog.pusher.com/create-web-notifications-using-laravel-pusher/

The event code is pretty basic:

```
class NewExerciseEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Only (!) Public members will be serialized to JSON and sent to Pusher
     **/
    public $message;
    public $username;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        //$this->username = $username;
        //$this->message  = "{$username} liked your status";
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['new-exercise'];
    }
}
```

In EventServiceProvider.php I have this to trigger the event:

```
Exercise::created(function ($exercise) {
            // lets trigger NewExerciseEvent to send pusher notifications
            $url = $exercise->present()->url();
            $msg = 'I wanted to let you know I just added a new exercise: <a href = "' . $url .'">'. $exercise->title . '</a>. Check it out!';
            event(new NewExerciseEvent($msg));
```

Existing blade view code that I used from above example is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var notificationsWrapper   = $('.dropdown-notifications');
            var notificationsToggle    = notificationsWrapper.find('a[data-toggle]');
            var notificationsCountElem = notificationsToggle.find('i[data-count]');
            var notificationsCount     = parseInt(notificationsCountElem.data('count'));
            var notifications          = notificationsWrapper.find('ul.dropdown-menu');

            if (notificationsCount <= 0) {
                notificationsWrapper.hide();
            }

            // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
            Pusher.logToConsole = true;

            var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxx', {
                encrypted: true
            });

            // Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('new-exercise');

            // Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
            channel.bind('App\\Events\\NewExerciseEvent', function(data) {
                var existingNotifications = notifications.html();
                var avatar = Math.floor(Math.random() * (71 - 20 + 1)) + 20;
                var newNotificationHtml = `
          <li class="notification active">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <div class="media-object">
                    <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/71/`+avatar+`.png" class="img-circle" alt="50x50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <strong class="notification-title">`+data.message+`</strong>
                  <!--p class="notification-desc">Extra description can go here</p-->
                  <div class="notification-meta">
                    <small class="timestamp">about a minute ago</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </li>
        `;
                notifications.html(newNotificationHtml + existingNotifications);

                notificationsCount += 1;
                notificationsCountElem.attr('data-count', notificationsCount);
                notificationsWrapper.find('.notif-count').text(notificationsCount);
                notificationsWrapper.show();
            });
        </script>
```

Just not sure where to go from here to extend to notification read/unread tracking. So, **some questions**:

1. For visitors, how do I obtain Laravel login info from Javascript?
2. For guests, to track read count, would it be enough to just use an onclick function to decrement the count?
3. For styling read vs unread, would I just use some jQuery function in 2 above to alter the styling?
4. For tracking logged in users' notifications, I know this will get more complicated, but will it boil down to creating notifications table and then in the route controller for reading the post to update notifications table?

Anyway, this is certainly not a trivial thing to do. If anyone knows of a simpler approach and example I am all ears! Or if someone can describe a game plan for what I would need to do in backend and frontend that would be great! I should mention I am not a pro developer. I am a guitarist with some coding experience who took over development after my developers found full time jobs...

thanks,

Brian